# DocuSign for Salesforce - Use Blob Content in Salesforce with SignHereTabs and Anchor-text

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Are there any methods in the latest 'DocuSign for Salesforce' package that allows for:
 - Using the Base64 content of a contentVersion as the document
 - Specifying SignHereTabs with Anchor-text within the document and assigning to specific recipients?

Would this need to be a custom integration with the REST API in order to facilitate this?

Answer (score 0):

Check page 70 of [DfS Guide](https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-for-salesforce-user-guide.pdf) to see how to do Automatic Anchor Text and Tags